# Show different div on clicking on the same button - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following

1. 2 different *div* with class names grey and yellow.
2. A button with click event bind on it with angular ng-click.

What i am trying

1. When clicking on the same button i want to show each of this div one at a time. for example when i click for the first time i want to show yellow div and on next click i want to hide yellow and show grey and so on.

Here is the code i have written

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
       <body  data-ng-app="myApp">
          <div data-ng-controller="myController">
             <article class="grey" ng-show="showMe">Grey</article>
             <article class="yellow" ng-show="showMe">Yellow</article>
             <button data-ng-click="toggleMe()">Click</button>
          </div>
          <script>
             var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
             myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
             $scope.showMe = false;
             $scope.toggleMe = function(){
             $scope.showMe = true;
             }
             });
          </script>
          <style>
             .grey{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:grey;}
             .yellow{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:yellow;}
          </style>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue ? Is it not working ?

Comment: Right now both div gets displayed. i want to displayed one at a time alternatively on same button click.

Answer (score 2):

https://plnkr.co/edit/ORJYrkpNPVR4h8DPOuVh?p=preview

```
               <div data-ng-controller="myController">
                     <article class="grey" ng-show="showMe">Grey</article>
                     <article class="yellow" ng-show="!showMe">Yellow</article>
                     <button data-ng-click="showMe = !showMe">Click</button>
                  </div>
                  <style>
                     .grey{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:grey;}
                     .yellow{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:yellow;}
                  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of JS here, Only this much of code will work in HTML only

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="showYellowAndHideGrey = true">
         <article class="grey" ng-show="showYellowAndHideGrey == false">Grey</article>
         <article class="yellow" ng-show="showYellowAndHideGrey == true">Yellow</article>
         <button ng-click="showYellowAndHideGrey = !showYellowAndHideGrey">Click</button>
</div>
```

working Example https://jsfiddle.net/1ms451sm/

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and past below code instead of your code

```js
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
                 myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
                 $scope.showMe = true;
                 $scope.toggleMe = function(){
                 $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe ;
                 }
                 });
```

```css
 .grey{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:grey;}
                 .yellow{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:yellow;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en-US">
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
           <body  data-ng-app="myApp">
              <div data-ng-controller="myController">
                 <article class="grey" ng-show="showMe">Grey</article>
                 <article class="yellow" ng-hide="showMe">Yellow</article>
                 <button data-ng-click="toggleMe()">Click</button>
              </div>              
           </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

showMe will be either true or false at a time. You need to bind the reverse value to both article element. so for achieving this, on one article you need to use ng-hide and on another you need to use ng-show.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
       <body  data-ng-app="myApp">
          <div data-ng-controller="myController">
             <article class="grey" ng-hide="showMe">Grey</article>
             <article class="yellow" ng-show="showMe">Yellow</article>
             <button data-ng-click="toggleMe()">Click</button>
          </div>
          <script>
             var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
             myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
             $scope.showMe = false;
             $scope.toggleMe = function(){
             $scope.showMe = true;
             }
             });
          </script>
          <style>
             .grey{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:grey;}
             .yellow{width:100%;max-width:300px;height:100px;background:yellow;}
          </style>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="showYellowAndHideGrey = true">
         <article class="grey" ng-if="showYellowAndHideGrey">Grey</article>
         <article class="yellow" ng-if="showYellowAndHideGrey">Yellow</article>
         <button ng-click="showYellowAndHideGrey = !showYellowAndHideGrey">Click</button>
</div>
```

or if you have common content and only want to toggle color you can use ng-class

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="showYellowAndHideGrey = true">
             <article ng-class="showYellowAndHideGrey? 'grey' : 'yellow'" ng-if="showYellowAndHideGrey">Grey/Yellow</article>
             <button ng-click="showYellowAndHideGrey = !showYellowAndHideGrey">Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
For article 1 set  ng-hide="showMe"
and for article 2 set  ng-show="showMe"

Here is a sample code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="myController">
        <article class="grey" ng-hide="showMe">Grey</article>
        <article class="yellow" ng-show="showMe">Yellow</article>
        <button data-ng-click="toggleMe()">Click</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.showMe = false;
            $scope.toggleMe = function () {
                $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .grey {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            background: grey;
        }
        
        .yellow {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is same as my answer !

Comment: I didn't look at other answers. I just posted when I saw the question.

Comment: No problem dude. I know your feel